# Changing style in collapsible elements in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to change the style of a collapsible element in JQuery Mobile: the element should not have any border and be completely white. I have tried the following:

```
 <div class="ui-block-a" data-role="collapsible"  data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" style="width: 74%; margin-left: 9px; border-width: 0px; background-color:white">
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>This is a mock.</p>
            </div>
```

However it seems that certain CSS don't work. Does anyone know if it's possible?

Comment: Values are separated from keys by colon `:`, not equal sign `=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/GNAXT/

It must be done through css, also collapsible element must have its own id if you don't want to change every element that uses collapsible css classes.

!important is important because it is used to override original properties.

```
#custom-collapsible {
    width: 74% !important; 
    margin-left: 9px !important; 
    border-width: 0px !important; 
    background-color: white  !important;
}

#custom-collapsible h3 a {
    border-width: 0px !important; 
    background: white  !important;
}
```